# How do I make time.sleep() work with tkinter?

Tags: python, time, tkinter

I'm trying to show a sequence of numbers on the screen at regular intervals.

I'm new to python so it may be something obvious but I have tried `.after` and `pygame.time.wait`, but neither worked.

this is the code:

```
from tkinter import*
from random import *
import time



my_list = []




def Create_NUM(event):
    x = 0

    for x in range(level + 2):
        button1.destroy()
        num = randint(1, 100)
        my_list.append(num)
        Label(root, text=num,fg="red").pack()
        one.pack()
        time.sleep(2)





root=Tk()

num = 0
level = 1
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

button1 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Click to start game",fg="red")
button1.bind("<Button-1>", Create_NUM)
button1.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: don't use `sleep()` - use `root.after(milliseconds, function_name, arguments)` instead of `sleep()` and `for` loop

Comment: Keep in mind that right now `bind` makes your button only work when clicked with mouse. You should try using `command` option for a more standard way of using buttons.

Comment: see example which display [current time](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/timer-using-after/clock-function.py)

Comment: There are dozens of questions on this site related to timers, sleep, and the `after` method. Have you done any research before asking this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to show new number in place of old number, not below it.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def start():
    # hide button
    button.pack_forget()
    # run `add_number` first time
    add_number(level+2)

def add_number(x):

    num = random.randint(1, 100)
    my_list.append(num)
    label['text'] = num

    if x > 0:
        # repeat after 2000ms (2s)
        root.after(2000, add_number, x-1)
    else:
        # show button again after the end
        button.pack()      

# --- main ---

my_list = []
level = 1

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click to start game", command=start)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this simple command in your function `root.update()`