# Python tkinter time.sleep() alternative

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm using tkinter for gui programming. I have a data frame, I get each data here with a 'for' loop. But I want it to wait 1 second for each data, but tkinter is not responding because I use 'time.sleep'. I will hold 1 second for each data and is there an alternative that won't freeze the 'tkinter'?

```
import pandas as pd 
from tkinter import * 

def print_rows(startRow):
    df = pd.read_excel(r'./x.xlsx')   
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if row.Index >= int(startRow):
            L1.config(text=str(row.Index)+'-'+ row.email)
            window.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: research tkinter's `after` method.

Comment: Check out this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621977/how-do-i-make-time-sleep-work-with-tkinter)

Comment: thanks your replies BryanOakley , AlbertoCastillo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = Tk()
x.after(miliseconds,function)
```

That's pretty much it.